# Excel Error 1004 For paste special

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to Macros and VBA and am receiving an error message "1004 Application defined or object defined error" when using paste special.

This is the code:

```
For rowCount = 1 To 11
     For lngCol = 1 To 8
          ws.Cells(rowCount, lngCol).Copy
          wb.Sheets(1).Cells(rowCount, lngCount).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlAll
     Next
Next
```

ws is a defined worksheet and wb is a defined workbook

Everything works when:

```
For rowCount = 1 To 11
            For lngCol = 1 To 8
                wb.Sheets(1).Cells(rowCount, lngCol).Value = ws.Cells(rowCount, lngCol).Value
            Next
Next
```

I just need to be able to keep the formatting

Comment: What is `lngCount`? should it be `lngCol`?

Comment: Try xlPasteAll instead of xlAll

Comment: Sorry they are supposed to be the same, I typed that in wrong in the question.  In the excel file they are both lngcol

Comment: Thank you, it is working now

Comment: You can copy and paste the code in the question, no need to retype the code.